# QT application couldn't be built in Linux?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I created a simple QT application using QT5 in windows.  Now I would like to compile the same application in Linux.  One issue is Linux QT is of an old version, yet I think it should compile because it is very simple with no use to special features in QT5.

In the Linux environment, the versions are as follow:

```
-- by typing qmake -v
Qmake : 1.07a (QT 3.3.8)
```

The project is simply a blank QApplication , which I create in windows.

In the .pro file, it is using  QT += widgets

In Linux all I tried to do is copy the whole project, then use qmake to generate the Makefile. The compiler throws an error of :

```
QApplication : no such file or directory
QApplication was not declared in this scope
```

The problem is clearly about version incompatibility, but it proved tricky for this rookie to fix.

Btw, QtCore is in /usr/include/QtCore

Comment: Do you also have `QApplication` in `/usr/include`?

Comment: What Linux box are you using? For having Qt **3** by default it must come from the neolithic era or something like that... Also, remember that Qt breaks compatibility at major release change; Qt 5 programs won't build even with Qt 4; most importantly, while the adjustments that need to be made between Qt 4 and Qt 5 are relatively minor, the break between Qt 3 and Qt 4 was way more serious.

Comment: QtCore suggests a Qt4 or Qt5 is installed though. So maybe check if you can just uninstall qt3-dev (or whatever the package containing the qmake is called) and install the qt5 equivalent.

Comment: It's also possible to install the newest official Qt SDK on Linux, too.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen, but unfortunately I can't install anything as there is significant portion of the code dependent on legacy code, and hence...I am obliged to either use available qt.

Answer (score 3):

Your Qt version is not just old but ancient (Qt3). It won't compile your Qt5 code, period. Even the headers have changed, `<QApplication>` simply does not exist in Qt3.